# In C++ is it possible to template a method with unknown amount of parameters, and specify the number of parameters in the override definition?

Tags: c++, class, methods, parameters

I have two classes (BaseClass, DerrivedClass), and I want to create a virtual method in BaseClass that has an undefined amount of parameters. The amount of parameters (if any) should be defined within the DerrivedClasses override of the method.
The BaseClass definition can be either abstract or not, but preferably it is abstract. The reason I would like this is so that I can force every subclass of BaseClass to override the definition with it's own unique values.

Is this possible, or just wishful thinking?

```
class BaseClass
{
    public:
        // I want to be able to override this method with as many parameters as the DerrivedClass desires, without having to make a version of it in BaseClass.
        virtual AssignValues() = 0;
}

class DerrivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:
        void AssignValues(const std::string& value1, const int value2) override
        {
            m_value1 = value1;
            m_value2 = value2;
        };
    private:
        std::string m_value1;
        int m_value2;
}

class DerrivedClass2 : public BaseClass
{
    public:
        void AssignValues(const int value) override
        {
            m_value = value;
        };
    private:
        int m_value;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
DerrivedClass example1;
DerrivedClass2 example2;

example1.AssignValues("Test Name", 1);
example2.AssignValues(2);
```

Comment: What would be the point of this approach? Generally, the point of inheritance is to implement polymorphism, i.e., code should be able to treat any subclass of `BaseClass` the same, without being aware of whether it's `DerivedClass` or `DerivedClass2` under the hood. It's hard to treat `DerivedClass::AssignValues()` and `DerivedClass2::AssignValues()` the same way if they have different numbers of arguments.

Comment: I second @jjramsey . Nothing in your example relies on `BaseClass` even existing. Show an example usage that relies on the fact that `DerrivedClass` and `DerrivedClass2` have a common base class, and wouldn't work if they don't. While you attempt to construct this example, I expect you'll discover why your proposed arrangement doesn't really make sense.

Comment: To be even more explicit, what you want to do is not the way inheritance is expected to work. Full stop. If you managed to find a way to compile this anti-patterns, you should prepare for maintenance nightmares...

Comment: The purpose is that it forces the subclass to define and override the virtual function (AssignValues). Used in conjunction with a singleton class, this opens up the possibility to define a thread safe templated Singleton class while at the same time clearly defining the need for variable assignment.

Comment: Then throw out the base class and just have the templated singleton check that the type parameter defines such a method via concept or requires clause.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve seems a design flaw to me, but if this is really needed, the closest you can get is a virtual member function with a single polymorphic argument capable of carrying all the needed information.
In my first example I have used std::variant, so the types need to be known upfront.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <variant>


struct Vals
{
    int x{};
    char y{};
};

using SetterArgs = std::variant<Vals, double>;

struct Base
{
    virtual void setValues(const SetterArgs&) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};


struct Der1 : Base
{
    int val1;
    char val2;

    void setValues(const SetterArgs& a) override
    {
        const auto& v = std::get<Vals>(a);
        val1 = v.x;
        val2 = v.y;
    }
};

struct Der2 : Base
{
    double val;

    void setValues(const SetterArgs& a) override
    {
        const auto& v = std::get<double>(a);
        val = v;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Der1 d1;
    static_cast<Base&>(d1).setValues(Vals{82, 'z'});
    std::cout << d1.val1 << ' ' << d1.val2 << '\n';

    Der2 d2;
    static_cast<Base&>(d2).setValues(3.14);
    std::cout << d2.val << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eM9eYd8e3

`std::any` could work here as well

```cpp
#include <any>


struct Vals
{
    int x{};
    char y{};
};

struct Base
{
    virtual void setValues(const std::any&) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};


struct Der1 : Base
{
    int val1;
    char val2;

    void setValues(const std::any& a) override
    {
        const auto& v = std::any_cast<Vals>(a);
        val1 = v.x;
        val2 = v.y;
    }
};

struct Der2 : Base
{
    double val;

    void setValues(const std::any& a) override
    {
        const auto& v = std::any_cast<double>(a);
        val = v;
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cGWY4h3qY

Comment: patch to a flawed design is never a good soution